# Use geom_curve() to make an arrow without x and xend argument

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have a seemingly small problem. I want to plot an arrow with `geom_curve()` on top of a bar chart within ggplot. The goal is to point out a single value from the bar chart.

In every other case, in order to plot the arrow with `geom_curve()`, we need to fill in the arguments `x`, `xend`, `y` and x `yend`. However, when plotting a bar chart with `geom_bar()`, the`aes(x = x)` is not specified. My question is how are we able to plot the arrow, even without specifying the `x` arguments.

Some sample code can be found below. How to use `geom_segment()` can be found [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_segment.html). Any help would be much appreciated

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)

tbl <- tibble(
  Var1 = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8),
  pct  = c(rep(0.2, 5))
) %>% 
  mutate(Var1 = Var1 %>% as_factor() %>% fct_rev())


tbl %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = pct, fill = Var1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_tq() +
  geom_text(aes(label = if_else(Var1 == 0, "20 %", "")), nudge_y = -0.025, nudge_x = 0.55, size = 5, color = "#2C3E50")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like that ? Or did I misunderstand your question ?

In `ggplot2`, even if you don't have x axis values, each bar of a bargraph can be associated to a number starting at 1.
So, if you have two bar on your graph, their x position are 1 and 2.

Here, you have only one bar, you can use that to add your arrow slight up to 1 (here I choose 1.50)

```r
tbl %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = pct, fill = Var1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  #scale_fill_tq() +
  geom_text(aes(label = if_else(Var1 == 0, "20 %", "")), nudge_y = -0.025, nudge_x = 0.55, size = 5, color = "#2C3E50")+
  geom_segment(x = 1.50, xend = 1.50, y = 0.1, yend = 0.75, arrow =  arrow(length = unit(0.03, "npc")))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: @ dc37 it wasn't exactly what I intended to do, but I didn't specify that in my question. The fact that a bargraph can be associated with a x position, even when it isn't explicitly specified did the trick. Thanks! I updated the code and got it working.

Comment: @Liri, glad that my answer help you to figure it out the solution to your problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @dc37, I got the arrow at the right place and pointing to a specific part of the bar chart.

```
tbl %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = pct, fill = Var1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(aes(label = if_else(Var1 == 0, "20 %", "")), nudge_y = -0.05, nudge_x = 0.51, size = 5, color = "#2C3E50") +
  geom_curve(aes(x = 1.51, xend = 1.46, y = 0.1, yend = 0.05), curvature = 1, color = "#2C3E50", arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.02, "npc")))
```

[image]